# How to set width and height on local image using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set width and height before displaying on the image gallery.

```
import ap1 from './Images/ap1.jpg';

const images = [ {original: ap1, thumbnail: ap1}]
```

How to set width and height inside in `{original: ap1, thumbnail: ap1}` ?

Comment: plz, do not delete your question :D Thank you.

Comment: plz give me a answer

Comment: just show me how you use 'images' ?

Comment: When you want to show an image you must use the img tag; you can give the width and the height properties on the tag.

Comment: I not have image tag.. look properly my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a reusable component trough my application:

```
 function PictureSizer ({img, height, width}) {
       return <img height={height} width={width} src={img} alt="Type something descriptive" />
    }
```

Then you can call that component with any height, width you want:

```
import ap1 from './Images/ap1.jpg';

<PictureSizer img={ap1} height={50} width={50} />;
```

Comment: Not worked for me :-( 
function PictureSizer ({img, height, width}) {
  return <img height={height} width={width} src={img} alt="Apartment" />
}

<PictureSizer img={ap1} height={50} width={50} />;

const images = [ {original: ap1, thumbnail: ap1}]

Comment: I made this example which is the same concept:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sky-ls6ov?file=/src/App.js